# In asp.net web.config, how to config the httphandlers?

Tags: asp.net, web-config, httphandler

The situation is that I want all the file types to be handled by a specified dll **except 'aspx' file**.

But I don't know how to edit the configuration file. As below:

```
<system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
         <add verb="*" path="*" type="My.Handler" />
    </httpHandlers>
</system.web>
```

All the requests will be handled by My.Handler. How to make the aspx file be accessed normally?

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: what kind of error? no error.

Comment: Are you really running IIS6 or in Classic mode?

Answer (score 5):

I have a "work around", but it's kind of "hacky" (and I only tested it locally as well)...

---

**1. Create the class below:**

```
public class PassThroughAspxHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
      var pageInstance = PageParser.GetCompiledPageInstance(context.Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath, 
                                                            context.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + context.Request.Path, 
                                                            context);
      pageInstance.ProcessRequest(context);
    }


    public bool IsReusable
    {
      get { return false; }
    }
  }
```

---

**2. Add the entry to your web config below:** 
(this part is for IIS7 integrated app pools, it will be slightly different if you are using a classic app pool):

```
 <system.webServer>
     <handlers>
       <add verb="*" path="*.aspx"
        name="PassThroughAspxHandler"
        type="YourNameSpaceHere.PassThroughAspxHandler"/>
     </handlers>
   </system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just a guess but try adding this after the one you came up with:

```
<add verb="*" path="*.aspx" type="System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory"/>
```

Comment: @roast_soul define "doesn't work". Did it not work because you navigated to "/"? What happens if nav to "/default.aspx"?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, adding some to Robert's post

```
<add verb="*" path="*.aspx" type="Your handler class name"/>
```

refer to  [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227439%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)